# 2nd Monitor not displaying properly

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Dell latitude laptop that is connected to a Dell universal d6000 docking station, and connected to a Samsung monitor via a HDMI cable. The problem i have is when I connect to the monitor, the resolution becomes 640x480 and I can't change it. It's ok when I first connect the monitor to the docking station; but after I idle the computer and turn it on again, the resolution goes off. Also, the Display settings show that the second monitor isn't detected but it identifies it the second screen at the same time. The monitor works perfectly when i plug it directly  into the laptop, meaning there is no problem with the monitor or the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1):

Ooo, Dell Latitudes. Not bad workbooks and easy to work on. Have you checked for any [driver updates](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-universal-dock-d6000/drivers) for the docking station? Not sure what it looks like for Latitudes but Lenovo T series laptops often need driver updates for the docking stations when they act up. Or it could be a faulty cable or station itself.